# Select closest discrete value algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I need to crowd source an algorithm needed for work. The problem: the user gives an integer as input. We must select the closest discrete "increment", within a certain range. Assume 0 is always an acceptable return value. We also have max and min values.

So, if min is -5, max is 5, and increment is 5, the acceptable return values are -5, 0, 5. If input is over the max we simply return max, if under min we simply return the min. For example, if the input is "3", our return value would be 5, since that is the closest increment to 3.

Does the following code cover all the cases?

```
int findClosestIncrement(int input)
{
   int min = getMin();
   int max = getMax();

   //delta is the "increment"
   int delta = getDelta();

   if(input <= min)
      return min;
   if(input >= max)
      return max;

   return Math.round( (float) input / float (delta) ) * delta;
}
```

Again, this is a real world problem.

Comment: if this is Java, please add java tag

Comment: Consider writing test cases to exercise the code.

Comment: If min is -3 and increment is 5, is 2 an acceptable value?

Comment: min -4 max -4 input 3 delta 5 returns 5? I think it would be easier to prove this was correct if the checks against min and max came after the round, and not before.

Comment: "Assume 0 is always an acceptable return value." - does this imply that the increments start go up and down in steps of delta from zero, and not starting from the min? What if the min is greater than zero, surely 0 is not an acceptable value then? If the min is 7, max is 17, and delta is 5, are the valid values 7, 10, 15, 17, or 7, 12, 17?

Comment: Looks fine to me provided `min` and `max` are multiples of `delta`.